# mongoDB search Text error

Tags: mongodb

there is an error when using searching index, i use v3.4.

```
> db.test2.insert({string:"aa bb cc"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test2.insert({string:"aa 88 99"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test2.ensureIndex({'string':"text"});


{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Index: { v: 2, key: { _fts: \"text\", _ftsx: 1 }, name: \"string_text\", ns: \"test2.test2\", weights: { string: 1 }, default_language: \"english\", language_override: \"language\", textIndexVersion: 3 } already exists with different options: { v: 2, key: { _fts: \"text\", _ftsx: 1 }, name: \"post_text_text\", ns: \"test2.test2\", weights: { post_text: 1 }, default_language: \"english\", language_override: \"language\", textIndexVersion: 3 }",
        "code" : 85,
        "codeName" : "IndexOptionsConflict"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may have already index for `string` field. To check previous indexes run this command

```
db.test2.getIndexes();
```

if exist then can remove that index by this instruction

```
db.test2.dropIndex( { "string": 1 } );
```

after that you can create index again for `string` field

```
db.test2.createIndex( { string: "text" } );
```

N.B: field name should not use like variable type name `string` (although you not used `String`), `Int`

Comment: actually it is first time i set this text index.  i tried your method, it shows  "code" : 27, "codeName" : "IndexNotFound". although not found, i still get this error message when i set index "code" : 85,"codeName" : "IndexOptionsConflict"

Comment: May I ask if i can set only one index by text? because i set other key's index text before, not sure if it impacts on it. if yes, could you help tell me how to drop all indexes? because i couldn't remember what index by text i set already.

Comment: possible multiple text index and you can see all indexes by this command `db.test2.getIndexes();` and to delete all index for this collection use `db.test2.dropIndex( "*" );` and change the field name `string` to another that not related to `data type`

Comment: thanks a lot. i verified that MongoDB only accept one text index. if you have to setup another one, then have to delete the previous one.